# Is a manifest file needed for non-managed code?

Tags: c#, c++, security, manifest, uac

Before I begin let me apologize for my nearly nonexistent knowledge of programing for UAC. That said…

I have a c# application that starts the setup.exe of a totally different program. Its main purpose is to help that second program run under UAC. So in a nutshell it runs that programs setup.exe file under an elevated command prompt. I have no control over that second program, so getting it to be UAC compatible is not an option. I wrote my program when Vista was first released and there was little UAC info to be found. Now keep in mind that running that setup.exe file this way in fact works, and allows the program to be run with UAC on. But part of my program also adds a “theirapp.exe.manifest” file with “requireAdministrator” as the Execution level. So my question is this, do I even need that file when the program I’m ultimately trying to run is a non-managed application (CBuilder C++). Somewhere along the way I believed a manifest file was needed. But now I’m told they only work for .NET apps.

Thanks

EDIT: To sum it up... Is manifest file needed to run a non-managed program under UAC?

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel
        level="requireAdministrator"
        uiAccess="false"/>
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
</trustInfo>
```

EDIT: My main method for running the OTHER programs setup.exe

```
private void RunElevated()
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/C " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"setup.exe");
    processInfo.Verb = "runas";

    try
    {
        Process.Start(processInfo);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Manifest files are *not* only for managed (.NET) applications. The two concepts have nothing to do with one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348877/what-purpose-do-unmanaged-dll-manifest-files-serve) answers my question. I suppose the fact that it refers to a manifest file for an un-managed DLL threw off my search.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual C++ you'll find the options under the Manifest options (part of the Linker settings):

[image: UAC settings in Visual Studio 11 (beta)]

Comment: The program I want need to run under UAC is not mine and I have no control over it. Its also written with CBuilder and not Visual C++.

Comment: You should still be able to use a manifest file sitting next to the executable (not sure if CBuilder is able to embed it properly). As an alternative approach, you could create the child process requesting elevated privileges for it (like many setup bootstraps do). EDIT: Just to clarify: Your own wrapper/loader is written using CBuilder and the to be launched program is essentially proprietary/closed source?

Comment: No, my wrapper is C# and the app I want to run under UAC is C++ and I cant change it. I added the main method to above. I just add the manifest file after that process is done. I'm just not sure whether it needs to be there. When I test, sometimes I find its needed and sometimes it isn't.